# How to build a Gradle plugin project together with a subproject that uses it?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle project with several modules among which I have a module implementing a Gradle plugin (`plugin-subproject`) and a module with a showcase of this plugin (`sample-subproject`):

```
plugin-subproject
│   build.gradle
sample-subproject
│   build.gradle
other subprojects...
│   build.gradle   
build.gradle
```

In the `sample-subproject`, I have a dependency on the plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "myplugin:gradle-plugin:0.1.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "myplugin.plugin"
```

It has to take the plugin from the local repository.

**Problem:** In order to build the `sample-subproject`, the plugin has to be installed into local Maven repository. But I cannot install it because if I run `./gradlew :plugin-subproject:install` it fails.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':sample-subproject'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':sample-subproject:classpath'.
> Could not find myplugin:gradle-plugin:0.1.0.
    Searched in the following locations:
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/myplugin/gradle-plugin/0.1.0/gradle-plugin-0.1.0.pom
    - file:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/myplugin/gradle-plugin/0.1.0/gradle-plugin-0.1.0.pom
    - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/myplugin/gradle-plugin/0.1.0/gradle-plugin-0.1.0.pom
    Required by:
        project :sample-subproject
```

I can remove the `sample-subproject`, install the plugin to the local maven repository and then I can successfully add and build the sample project. But it is a hack, I want to solve the issue in a standard way.

**Question:** How can I build a Gradle plugin project together with a subproject that uses it?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you [need this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources)

Comment: Eugene is correct. If you have a Gradle plugin in your project that is used by your project, it should be implemented in `buildSrc`.

Comment: You can depend on the _latest published_ version by using `+` for the classpath version: `classpath "myplugin:gradle-plugin:0.1.+"`. You won't be able to use the current version, however.

Comment: @Phil thast is what I am doing, but it is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Your can add line in main `build.gradle`:

```
build.dependsOn ":plugin-subproject:build"
```

P.S.
There is way to define modules in `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'project-name'

include "plugin-subproject"
include "sample-subproject"
include "other subprojects"
```

and make dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':plugin-subproject')
}
```

but there is no documentary evidence that this is the correct way to do the correct order of assembling modules.

Comment: Thank you. The `plugin-subproject` is [a Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project). It doesn't need to be in the dependencies, it has to be in the `buildscript` section as it is involved in *building* `sample-subproject`. Nevertheless, I tried it out. Unfortunately I get the same error.